# displaying more posts on the edit screen in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a way to increase the amount of posts displaying in the admin edit screen when i click on the posts tab.

I have had a look around the net and found the following function:

```
function customize_admin(){
global $per_page;
$per_page = 500;
```

}

This doesnt seem to be working. any ideas if the code above is correct?

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out there is actually an option under screen options to change this!